# Run PHP code only if it's been 1 hour since last run

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, scope, static-variables

So I've got a bunch of database and wordpress querying going on to create a leaderboard.
Querying data, calculating, and then updating seems like a lot to do and really slows the leaderboard display page down. So I'm trying to get the querying and calculating to only happen if it's been over an hour since the last time it was queried. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
    static $lastQueryTime;

    if( !isset($lastQueryTime) || ($now > $lastQueryTime + (60*60)) ){
        $lastQueryTime = $now;

        //PHP to run...Querying, calculating, updating
    }
?>
```

I've also tried  "global" instead of "static", but neither seemed to work, the querying always happens on page load.

Comment: You would need to store the value outside of PHP (which is executed runtime). The most likely option is a SQL database (MySQL), the fastest option would be a cache server (Redis), and the fastest to set up would be a static file (that you read/write directly).

Comment: Neither `global` nor `static` will do you any good here – because your PHP script only “lives” as long as it needs to answer the current request … after that, it is done, and all its variables are gone. You need to store the values somewhere where the next “instance” of your script can read it from again – a file, a database, …

Comment: Why don't you have your script run by `cron` simply?

Answer (score 2):

PHP code is stateless unless you make it so - `static` variables do not survive across requests, or more precisely nothing does unless you persist it manually.

You'll have to store `$lastQueryTime` on disk or in a database for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

`static` and `global` are not mechanisms that *persist data across separate instances*. They only retain data within a single script run, then all is gone. You need to store the data externally, in a database, a memcache, in a file etc.

Answer (score 0):

Write `$lastQueryTime` to a file at the end of you script and include that file at the top if your script.  Then test if `$lastQueryTime` is over an hour ago.  If it is, proceed with your script and save the new time to file.  Else, do nothing.